# Listen to specific changes on contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

**Warning: not duplicate with existing questions, read through**

I know I can have an **event** listen on changes on an `contenteditable` element.

What I would like is to be able to know **what the changes are**.

For example:

- inserted "This is a sentence." at position X.
- deleted from position X to Y.
- formatted from X to Y with `<strong>`

Is that possible? (**other than by doing a diff I mean**)

---

The reason for this is to make a WYSIWYG editor of other languages than HTML, for example Markdown.

So I'd like to apply the changes to the Markdown source (instead of having to go from HTML to Markdown).

Comment: It could be done with an excessive amount of code, it would definitely help to clarify a real-world example of what someone would do and what you're trying to do should they do it and most importantly why.

Comment: @John I've given a real world example: it's a WYSIWYG editor for Markdown.

Comment: WYSIWYG for Markdown? I tried once to implement HTML->MD converter (having already a great parser, I only needed an MD writer) and it turned out to be a pointless project because MD is so poor. You  will never be able to sync WYSIWYG (HTML mode) with source mode (MD output) well enough for professional project.

Comment: Please give practical and rational explanation on why diff is not acceptable solution. This is like asking how to add 2 numbers to together (other than using addition operator I mean). FML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to do something with [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)s (falling back to D[OM Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) in older browsers, although IE <= 8 supports neither) but I suspect it will still be hard work to achieve what you want.

Here's a simple example using MutationObservers:

http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/4n2Gz/

Comment: @crl: Works for me on both. Perhaps you're editing the wrong thing? I admit the example isn't very clear.

Comment: ah, yeah `[contenteditable] {border: 1px solid;}` helps to figure out what to edit, thx

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is no way to find out what the changes are without doing a diff between the original content and the modified one when changes occur.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this

```
var strong=document.createElement("strong");
var range=window.getSelection().toString().getRangeAt(0);
range.surroundContents(strong);
```

this was for third part

You just need to select what you want to surround using real User interaction.

If you wanna do it dynamically

```
var range=document.createRange();
range.setStart(parentNode[textNode],index to start[X])
range.setEnd(parentNode[textNode],index to end[Y])
range.surroundContents(strong);
```

For 2nd Part

```
range.deleteContents()
```

1st part can be done by using simple iteration

var textnode=// node of the Element you are working with

```
textnode.splitText(offset)
```

offset- position about which text node splitting takes place[here==X]
Two child Nodes have been created of the parent editable Element

Now use simple insertBefore() on parent editable Element Node.

hope you will find it useful

Comment: Combine this with MutationObserver et voilà :)

Answer (score -2):

The API you're looking for does not exist, as DOM nodes do not store their previous states.

The data / events you're wishing to get back are not native implementations in any browser Ive come across, and I struggle to think of a datatype that would be able to generically handle all those cases. perhaps something like this:

```
function getChanges() {

    /* do stuff here to analyse changes */

    var change = {
        changeType : 'contentAdded',
        changeStart : 50, /* beginning character */
        changeContent : 'This is a sentence'
    }

    return change;
}
```

Since you're trying to get custom events / data, you're probably going to need a custom module or micro-library. Either way, to look at the *changes* of something, you need somehow be aware of *what has changed*, which can only be done by comparing what it was to what it is now.